# Find and return the element which occurs most frequently in an array

Tags: arrays, typescript, for-loop, return, mode

I need to implement a function called findMode to find the mode of an array. Assuming the array contains integer numbers only. When the function is called and the array is empty it returns 0. When the function is called and the array isn't empty it should return the element which occurs most frequently in an array. If an array contains multiple modes it should return the smallest value of the modes. I need to create an intermediate array, another array of numbers to count the number of times each value occurs. This array should use the index numbers of the array to track of how many times a number in b has been counted.

below is what I have so far:

```
import { print } from "....";

export let main = async () => {
    let input = [2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0]
    print(mode(input))

};

export let findMode = (b: number[]): number => {
    let newArr: number[] = []; /** this is the new number array created to store count, this is the intermediate array */
    if (b.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {


};
main();
```

Here are the expected/actual results:

If the array is b[2,1,1,2,1,0] then 1 should be returned, and if we printed the array we created to store the count it should print newArr[1,3,2] because element 0 has 1 occurrence, element 1 has 3 occurrences, and element 2 has 2 occurrences. The idea is to go from 0 as an element in our input array to it 0 being an index in our intermediate array. so lastly we see which is our max occurrences ( or max element in our intermediate array) which is 3 at index 1, so the mode is 1.

If the array is b[0,0,0,1,1,2,1,1] then 1 should be returned. If the array is b[4,4,7,4,0,7] then 4 should be returned. If the array is b[-4,-4,-1,3,5] then -4 should be returned. If the array is b[1,1,2,3,2] then 1 should be returned since its the smallest of the modes. If the array is b[10,10,10,20,20,30] then 10 should be returned.

Comment: that's a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
export let findMode = (b: number[]): number => {
    // we'll store the values in b and the number of times they occur here
    const counts: Array<{ value: number, count: number }> = [];

    // it helps to check that b is defined before you check length, this avoids ReferenceErrors
    if (!b || !b.length) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        const val = b[i];
        const count = counts.find(count => count.value === val);

        if (count) {
            count.count++;
        } else {
            counts.push({ value: val, count: 1 });
        }
    }

    // get the mode by sorting counts descending and grabbing the most occuring
    const mode = counts.sort((c1, c2) => c2.count - c1.count)[0];

    // and now if you *need* an intermediate array with the index mapped to the value and value mapped to the count:
    const largestNumber = counts.sort((c1, c2) => c2.value - c1.value)[0];
    // initialize an empty as long as the largest number
    let newArr = new Array(largestNumber);
    newArr = newArr.map((val, i) => {
        const count = counts.find(count => count.value === i);
        if (count) {
            return count.count;
        } else {
            return 0; // 'i' occurs 0 times in 'b'
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to achieve the result with an additional object for keeping count.

```
export let findMode = (b: number[]): number => {
  // object for keeping count of each element
  // initially set `0` with 0 count (default value)
  let ref = {
    '0': 0
  };

  return b.reduce((value, num) => {
    // define count as 0 if not defined 
    ref[num] = ref[num] || 0;

    // increment element count
    ref[num]++;
    // if number count is gretater than previous element count
    // then return current element
    if (ref[num] > ref[value]) {
      return num;
    // if counts are same then return the smallest value
    } else if (ref[num] === ref[value]) {
      return num < value ? num : value;
    }
    // else return the previous value
    return value;
    // set initial value as 0(default)
  }, 0);
};
```

```js
let findMode = b => {

  let ref = {
    '0': 0
  };

  return b.reduce((value, num) => {
    ref[num] = ref[num] || 0;
    ref[num]++;
    if (ref[num] > ref[value]) {
      return num;
    } else if (ref[num] === ref[value]) {
      return num < value ? num : value;
    }
    return value;
  }, 0);
};


[
  [2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0],
  [1, 3, 2],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
  [4, 4, 7, 4, 0, 7],
  [-4, -4, -1, 3, 5],
  [1, 1, 2, 3, 2],
  [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 30]
].forEach(v => console.log(findMode(v)))
```